# Wordpress: showing logo in header by scrolling

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for help. I have a logo in the header, which is always shown. I would like to change the logo in such a way that it is hidden in the beginning, but appearing after scrolling the page. How can I change the setting? I guess that's done with php, isn't? Is there anybody who can help me? Thank you very much!

Kind regards,
pradhana

Answer (score 1):

What you want cannot be done neither with PHP, nor with any language that is **Server-Side**. You can do this with jQuery **scroll and scrollTop** functions.

jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>300){ // active if scrolled 300px
        $( "#header" ).addClass( "hide-logo" );
    }
    else{
        $( "#header" ).removeClass( "show-logo" );
    }
});
```

css

```
.hide-logo{
  display:none;
  transition:0.3s;
}
.show-logo{
  display:block;
  transition:0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Where do I paste the first code. I mean this one: .hide-logo{
  display:none;
  transition:0.3s;
}
.show-logo{
  display:none;
  transition:0.3s;
}

Comment: Sorry, I mean that: $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>300){ // active if scrolled 300px
        $( "#header" ).addClass( "hide-logo" );
    }
    else{
        $( "#header" ).removeClass( "show-logo" );
    }
});

Comment: First of all, you need to get the logic of creating and developing websites as graphical. Because HTML, CSS and Javascript doing that. You need to download a javascript library jQuery to make what you want happen.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by js, not php. Make the logo default display:none and when user scroll, make it visible

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
  //make your image visible
}
```